# Derivative operator on polynomial space $P[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $P[0,1]$ be the space of real polynomial function on$[0,1]$ with $\|p\|= sup\{|p(x)|:0\leq x \leq 1\}. T(p)(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(p(x)).$ Then it is clear that $T$ is not a bounded operator. How to discuss the closeness of this operator. Is it close or not? If we consider the same operator on the space $C^{1}[0,1]$ then it is closed. But I am confused on the space $P[0,1]$. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean on ${\cal C}^1[0,1]$?

Comment: No its polynomial space..

Comment: No, I mean when you say "consider the same on ${\cal C}[0,1]$." $T$ is not defined on that space.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider ${d\over {dx}}:P[0,1]\rightarrow P[0,1]$ it is closed.

Let $p_n=\sum_ia_n^ix^i$ be a family of polynomial which converges towards the polynomial $p=\sum_ib^ix^i$. The sequence $(a_n^i)$ converges towards $b^i$. This implies that the sequence $(ia_n^i)$ converges towards $ib^i$ and $\lim_n {d\over {dx}}p_n={d\over{dx}}p$.

If you consider ${d\over{dx}}:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ whose domain is $P[0,1]$ the result is not true. Consider $e^x=\sum_{i\geq 0}{x^i\over{i!}}$. Write $p_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}{x^i\over{i!}}$; $e^x=lim_np_n$ and $lim_n{d\over{dx}}p_n=e^x$. You don't have $e^x\in P[0,1]$.

Comment: Same as that for $C^{1}[0,1]$ ??

Comment: This is not the definition of a closed linear operator. What are the Banach spaces?

Comment: If you consider $P[0,1])$ has a subset of $C[0,1]$ then ${d\over {dx}}$ may not be closed, since a sequence of polynomials does not converge towards a polynomial necessarily.

Comment: Branch spaces are $C^{1} [0,1]$ ???

Comment: See this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators

Comment: Explain why you believe that the answer here is not true

Comment: What is shown here respect the definition that you quoted, if $p_n$ converges towads $p$ and ${d\over {dx}}p_n$ converges towards $q$ since the domain of the operator is $P[0,1]$ and its image is also $P[0,1]$, $p,q$ are polynomials.

Comment: No it's not. Where are the Banach spaces $X,Y$?

Comment: Can we consider the upper Banch space as $C^{1} [0,1]$ ???

Comment: One more thing sequence of polynomial may not converges to polynomial...

Comment: @zhw : If $X$, $Y$ are normed spaces and $T : \mathcal{D}(T) \subseteq X \rightarrow Y$ is linear with a linear domain, then $T$ is closed iff the graph of $T$ is a closed subspace of $X\times Y$. Equivalently, if $\{ x_n \} \subseteq\mathcal{D}(T)$ converges in $X$ to $x$ and $\{ Tx_n \}$ converges in $Y$ to $y$, then $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$ and $Tx=y$. Tsemo has pointed out an interesting case where $T$ is defined on polynomials.

Comment: @TrialAndError how a sequence of polynomial must converge to a polynomial ?

Comment: @Dahiya : A sequence $\{ \alpha_{0,n} + \alpha_{1,n} x + \cdots + \alpha_{N,n} x^N \}$ converges if the coefficient sequences converge. So that's one example. When you're trying to show $T$ is closed, you get to assume sequences $\{ p_n \}$ and $\{ Tp_n \}$ converge to polynomials $x$ and $y$, respectively; you don't care how that may happen. Then you have to show that $y=Tx$; if you can establish that, then $T$ is closed.